# Для чего подчеркивания в @property?

Tags: python

Всех приветствую. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Вот код:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 0
 
    @property
    def age(self):
        return self.__age
 
    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("Age cannot be negative")
        self.__age = value
        
t = Person()
t.age = 12
print(t.age) # 12
```

Он корректно работает, но меня смущает вот что: атрибут `Person` называется `age`, а геттеры и сеттеры взаимодействуют c `__age`. Я понимаю, что `__` заменяется на имя класса и получается `_Person__age`. Собственно, в коде так и получается:

```
print(dir(t))

# ['_Person__age', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'age']
```

При этом без дандеров я получаю ошибку:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 0
 
    @property
    def age(self):
        return self.age
 
    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("Age cannot be negative")
        self.age = value
        
t = Person()
t.age = 12
print(t.age)


File "main.py", line 47, in age
    if value < 0:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Вопросов несколько:

1. Зачем нужен атрибут с подчёркиванием, если они одинаковые:

   `t.age = 12`
   `print(t.age) # 12`
   `print(t._Person__age) # 12`

При этом `vars()` выводит только `{'_Person__age': 12}`

2. Почему без подчёркиваний получаю ошибку?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: `self.age` — это и есть property. Если вы внутри `def age` обращаетесь к `self.age`, то получается, что property обращается к property, который обращается к property, который обращается к property... и так пока не кончится место в стеке

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для данного кода, не касаясь искажения имен при наследовании: подчеркивания (два, одно или три) или любые другие символы нужны для того, чтобы переменная не называлась так же, как геттеры и сеттеры. Если они называются так же, как переменная, получается бесконечная рекурсия.
Когда вы в `__init__()` делаете присвоение `self.age = 0`, то не создается свойства `age`, а происходит вызов `age(self, 0)`, где создается свойство `__age` и ему присваивается значение 0.

Назовите свойство вместо `__age`, например, `rage` - будет работать так же.
Просто согласно [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) договорились о том, чтобы применять подчеркивания.

[Здесь подробные объяснения](https://sky.pro/media/odinarnye-i-dvojnye-podcherkivaniya-pered-imenem-obekta-v-python/)

Comment: Большое спасибо